# Find calls to typed functions which do not check the return value

Tags: gratis, c++, c, code-analysis

I want a tool to parse C / C++ (others welcome, particularly PHP, but C / C++ == priority) and find calls to typed functions which do not check the return value.

I don't see a g++ option (does MS have such an option).

Maybe something like [Splint](http://www.splint.org/)? Or is there an IDE which will let me check this? GUI and CLI solutions are both welcome.

Preferably Linux, but Windows is acceptable.

Must be gratis.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *check* the return value?   Use it in a predicate?  What's the use case for this?

Comment: I mean that a function returns a value, let’s say success/fail and the caller does not bother to check that value & act accordingly (just assumes success)

Comment: Then you insist that the result is used in a predicate.  Why is Steve's answer the "right one" in that case?

Comment: It's what I went with. Feel free t post another answer. I would rearward the answer if your post offered a better solution.

Comment: SR is supposed to be about *good* recommendations that match the requirements.  I don't feel that your choice matched the requirements you stated.  No, I don't have another answer with the constraints you have stated.

Comment: So, please help me to understand? Should i leave it unanswered? Maybe that would help others in future. As it is, I *do* feel that this answers my question - what makes you think that it doesn't? I think that I could learn something here. Thanks, Steve.

Comment: How can an answer that does not meet your requirement of "checks the the return value" be an answer?   Yes, I would have left it marked as unanswered.   Yes, Steve's response is probably useful, just not complete with respect to your requirements, so I would not delete it or downvote it.

Comment: Sorry, Ira, I must be totally dumb, but I am completely missing your point. I was code reading, found lots of places where a return value was not checked e.g. a call to `malloc()` and the code continued as if it were successful. To my mind, Steve's suggestion helps me detect that, as in the sample code which I posted as an answer. I have a horrible feeling that we are "speaking past each other" - what am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand the word "predicate"?  Your request appears to be for tool that verifies for a value-returning function foo, that every use of foo is equivalent to the following code:   [[x=foo(...); ...  if (...x...) ... ]]  where ... means "arbitrary code that that doesn't affect x".   Steve's answer at best handles detecting that every use of foo is equivalent to [[x=foo(...);]]; there's no *test* of x required.  Those look pretty different to me.

Comment: I see it now, sorry to have been so dim. maybe a good linter will help. Steve’s answer certainly helps a little, and, in practise I have not yet found a case of  `x = foo()` where x is not tested during code review (but it#s the kind of code where it wouldn’t surprize me to see that, alas :-(   Thanks for clarifying that. I will leave Steve with the answer until something better comes along.

Comment: All that will do is discourage the person with the right answer from providing it; after all, you've already chosen the wrong one.  (This isn't intended to be "against" Steve, just against marking the wrong answer.)

Comment: Ok, I agree. Since @Steve has 10.5k, I don't suppose he will be to upset if I unaward the answer ,-)   Let's see if someone comes up with a better answer. I am quite surprised that no one has mentioned a linter yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `gcc` you have the following options:

`-Wunused-result` *Warns if returned value is unused*
`-Wunused` *warn about a number of unused cases* and
`-Wall` (my favorite) turns on a bunch of warnings including -Wunused-result

A full list of gcc warning options can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

You can also use [function atributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) to set `warn_unused_result` so as to generate a warning if a specific functions return value is not used.

And of course `gcc` is free.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that. Also for g++ ? Only -Wunused-resul or do I need to add __attribute__((warn_unused_result to ecey function declaration?

Comment: I would just give it a try - most gcc flags also apply to g++

Comment: I am posting an answer, because I can't format code in a comment. Obviously, though, I am awarding you the answer and an upvote and my thanks.

Comment: "Unused" certainly implies "not checked" but it seems like a only a small subset.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, neither -Wunused-result nor -Wall worked in g++ v4.6.3. However, the function attribute which Steve suggested did.

```
int GenerateRandomNumber() __attribute__((warn_unused_result));

int GenerateRandomNumber()
{
   return 4;
}

int main()
{
    GenerateRandomNumber();

    return 0;
}
```

results in

> **** Build of configuration Debug for project unused_return_value ****
>
> make all  Building file: ../src/unused_return_value.cpp Invoking: GCC
>   C++ Compiler g++ -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
>   -Wunused-result -MMD -MP -MF"src/unused_return_value.d" -MT"src/unused_return_value.d" -o "src/unused_return_value.o" "../src/unused_return_value.cpp" ../src/unused_return_value.cpp: In
>   function ‘int main()’: ../src/unused_return_value.cpp:10:24: `warning:
>   ignoring return value of ‘int GenerateRandomNumber()’, declared with
>   attribute warn_unused_result` [-Wunused-result] Finished building:
>   ../src/unused_return_value.cpp   Building target: unused_return_value
>   Invoking: GCC C++ Linker g++  -o "unused_return_value" 
>   ./src/unused_return_value.o    Finished building target:
>   unused_return_value
>
> **** Build Finished ****

I might wrap the attribute in a #define.

I am also pushing strongly to use the "treat warnings as errors" option. I firmly believe that anyone who can craft a compiler knows more about the language than me (I struggled with the Dragon Book), so can never understand when people shrug ans say "it's only a warning".

I will also be pushing to use a Linter. And for code to be compiler and linter warning free before code review (results of both to be submitted with the code) and before release to version control.

Thanks, Steve!

Comment: Mawg - I would personally say blocking people from putting things under version control because they still have warnings/lint failures is not the best way to go as it can result in people not using version control - keep them on a branch until the quality criteria are met then allow onto the trunk might be a better way to go.